# Doctor Who - Sleep No More confusion

Tags: doctor-who

In the Doctor Who episode Sleep No More, does the fact that Clara went into the Morpheus machine (and got sleep dust in here eye?) mean she was infected somehow and would turn into one of the sandmen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of the episode, it was stated that the Morpheus device was not responsible for the change into sandmen; in fact it was all just a ploy by Professor Rassmussen for people to watch back home on Trident.

The "sandmen mutation" effect is actually caused by seeing some sort of code which triggers the body into becoming a sandman.

Comment: Are we to think that other parts of the Universe within Doctor Who might have been infected by this code that was transmitted or is the conceit just about viewers at home?  Basically, is everything meant to be tied up at the end of this episode?

Comment: Both, it was a fear factor for children - they saw it, they were infected; the video in the universe is for the people of Trident to watch, but for us we watched it. Everything is meant to be tied up, yes.